# Why are we allowed to refer to "Yisra'el" as "Ya'akov"?

Tags: halacha, names, avot-patriarch-fathers, vayishlach

The Torah states ([Bereshis 35:10](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8230#v=10)) that when G-d blessed Ya'akov, he says, "Your name shall no longer be called Ya'akov, but Yisra'el shall be your name". If so, why does God, and we are allowed to call him Ya'akov, whereas, we are not allowed to use the names "Avram" and "Sarai"?

Comment: this site discusses it http://www.torahweb.org/torah/1999/parsha/rsob_vayishlach.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Berachos 12b-13a

> כיוצא בו אתה אומר (בראשית לה, י) "לא יקרא שמך עוד יעקב כי אם ישראל יהיה שמך" לא שיעקר יעקב ממקומו אלא ישראל עיקר ויעקב טפל לו
>
> Similarly we find "Your name shall not be called Yaakov any longer, rather Yisrael shall be your name" - not that the name Yaakov is uprooted from its place, rather that Yisrael is the primary name and Yaakov is secondary to it.

According to the Gemara, the verse is saying that his name is no longer *only* Yaakov.

As far as to why he is different than Avraham, the Gemara further states:

> אלא מעתה הקורא ליעקב יעקב ה"נ שאני התם דהדר אהדריה קרא דכתיב (בראשית מו, ב) ויאמר אלהים לישראל במראות הלילה ויאמר יעקב יעקב

Hashem himself subsequently called him Yaakov.